# hibernate transation not starter successfully

Tags: java, hibernate

I have written below piece of code which checks if database connection is active or not. But I am getting an exception saying transaction not started successfully.

```
public static boolean checkSessionFactoryConnection() {
    boolean sessionAlive = false;
    Session session = null;
    String query = "select 1";
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.createSQLQuery(query).list();
        sessionAlive = true;
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.print(DBConnectionFactory.class, new String[] { "Connection to the database is lost. Resetting database connection." });
        if (session != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return sessionAlive;
}
```

Below is the exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:202)
at common.core.DBConnectionFactory.checkSessionFactoryConnection(DBConnectionFactory.java:166)
```

The above exception is coming in catch block at below line from code

```
session.getTransaction().rollback();
```

Can anybody please advise where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you print more stack trace?

Comment: maybe autocommit is enabled. then you have no need to start and end transactions

Comment: You swallow the real exception in the catch (Exception e) block. Check what is e by printStackTrace() to see real problem.